# Split string in Java to show only sequence of characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split a string like the string below

```
3x2y3+5x2w3–8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y–4xw–x2x3+8x2w3z4–4
```

to a table of strings which does not have any number or sign.

That means

```
a[0]=x
a[1]=y
a[2]=x
a[3]=w
```

I tried this

```
split("(\\+|\\-|\\d)+\\d*")
```

but it seems that it does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example what your result should look like according to the given input?

Comment: so you are only looking for letters? what about "xw" should that stay together or be split?

Comment: I want them to be together

Comment: Is it me or minus sign in `–8x2w3z4+3` and `-2x2w3+9y` are different?

Comment: @Pshemo.. It's not only you. Because they are really different. ;)

Comment: yes :) It is for a reason i don't know

Comment: yes they are differents, copy pasting them in emacs give different code. one - 0x2D and the other is UTF8 e28093 which explains why java does not parse them.

Answer (score 5):

The following should work:

```
String[] letters = input.split("[-+\\d]+");
```

Comment: This will result in many empty strings in array, resulting from splitting two back to back digits.

Comment: @RohitJain can you give an example or has the regex been fixed?

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. Ah! Yeah, my bad. It will work fine. Actually I used wrong regex. But why was this downvoted?

Comment: Sorry, your solution does not meet the requirement. Your solution excludes brackets for example, the requirement does not!

Comment: @stefanbachert.. Now it's fine. As per requirement.

Comment: yes, but it shows the "-" symbol, and it has an empty string in the beggining

Comment: testing it '[^a-zA-Z]+' :
**[0]=**
[1]=x
[2]=y
[3]=x
[4]=w
[5]=x
[6]=w
[7]=z
[8]=x
[9]=w
[10]=y
[11]=xw
[12]=x
[13]=x
[14]=x
[15]=w
[16]=z

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: -**

If you want `xw` to be together in your resulting array, then you would need to split your string: -

```
String[] arr = str.split("[-+\\d]+");
```

**Output: -**

```
[, x, y, x, w, x, w, z, x, w, y, xw, x, x, x, w, z]
```

---

You can replace all the unwanted characters with empty string, and split on empty string.

```
String str = "3x2y3+5x2w3-8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y-4xw-x2x3+8x2w3z4-4";
str = str.replaceAll("[-+\\d]", "");        
String[] arr = str.split("");       
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Note that, this will add an empty string as the first element of your array, which you can handle.

**Output: -**

```
[, x, y, x, w, x, w, z, x, w, y, x, w, x, x, x, w, z]
```

---

Note that `-` sign in your question is different. You should replace it with the one on your keyboard. Currently it is not matching `-` sign.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner does it all:

```
String[] letters = input.replaceAll("(^[^a-z]*)|([^a-z]*$)", "").split("[^a-z]+");
```

This also deals with leading/trailing characters so you don't get blank elements at the start of the array (like some other answers)

A test with your string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "3x2y3+5x2w3–8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y–4xw–x2x3+8x2w3z4–4";
    String[] letters = input.replaceAll("(^[^a-z]*)|([^a-z]*$)", "").split("[^a-z]+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
}
```

Output:

```
[x, y, x, w, x, w, z, x, w, y, xw, x, x, x, w, z]
```

Notice that there's no leading "blank" element in the array

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it does not work. yes, it keeps the numbers

Comment: I don't understand, why would numbers be kept?

Comment: @DoubleGras I originally had `"[^\\w]+"` but I changed it to `"[^a-z]+"` to fix the problem

Comment: That's what I thought. So, upvote of this answer which is the simplest one.

Comment: @Anonymous you may want to look at this answer again. I have refined it. It's still only one line, but it has bells and whistles too.

Comment: @assylias You were quite right (I can't believe I overlooked that - I'm usually the first to point that out to others :/ ) Better now ? :)

Answer (score 0):

**remark - and – are not same code, one is just ascii minus other is long ( coded UTF8 e28093 )**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String pArgs[])
    {
        String s="3x2y3+5x2w3–8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y–4xw–x2x3+8x2w3z4–4";
        String splitreg="(\\+|\\-|\\d|–)+\\d*";     if ( pArgs.length > 0 )
            {
                splitreg=pArgs[0];
        }
        System.out.println("splitting '" + s + "' with '"  + splitreg + "'"); 
        String[] splitted=s.split(splitreg);
        for (int i=0; i < splitted.length; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println("["+ i + "]" + "=" + splitted[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

*/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Test*

```
splitting '3x2y3+5x2w3–8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y–4xw–x2x3+8x2w3z4–4' with '(\+|\-|\d|–)+\d*'
[0]=
[1]=x
[2]=y
[3]=x
[4]=w
[5]=x
[6]=w
[7]=z
[8]=x
[9]=w
[10]=y
[11]=xw
[12]=x
[13]=x
[14]=x
[15]=w
[16]=z
```

Comment: in my case it does ( copy paste it ). there are two minus characters in initial string , one which is normal ascii one, and the other that is more a word editor one ( that is – UTF8 code : e28093, this – is not the one you can find on your keyboard, i think you got it by copy-pasting blogs or wikis...

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] letters = input.split("[\\d\\+\\-]+");
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `+` and `-`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
 String data="3x2y3+5x2w3–8x2w3z4+3-2x2w3+9y–4xw–x2x3+8x2w3z4–4";

 //lets replace all unnecessary elements with spaces
 data=data.replaceAll("[-+–\\d]", " ");
 // now string looks like:
 // " x y   x w   x w z     x w   y  xw x x   x w z   "

 // lets remove spaces from start and end
 data=data.trim();
 // data looks like:
 // "x y   x w   x w z     x w   y  xw x x   x w z"

 // and split in places where is at least one space
 String[] arr=data.split("\\s+");

 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[x, y, x, w, x, w, z, x, w, y, xw, x, x, x, w, z]
```